# Remove rows conditionally in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have got a dataframe and I would like to remove some duplicate rows by taking the ones with max values.

Here an example simplified of my dataframe:

```
    Code   Weight  Year
1   27009  289     1975
2   27009  300     1975
3   27009  376     1977
4   30010  259     1975
5   30010  501     1979
6   30010  398     1979
[....]
```

My output should be:

```
    Code   Weight  Year
1   27009  300     1975
2   27009  376     1977
3   30010  259     1975
4   30010  501     1979
[....]
```

Between Code and Weight I have got 5 more columns with different values and between Weight and Year one more column with still different values.

Should I use an if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `dplyr` package:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Code   Weight  Year
                         27009  289     1975
                         27009  300     1975
                         27009  376     1977
                         30010  259     1975
                         30010  501     1979
                         30010  398     1979", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df$x <- rnorm(6)

df %>% 
  group_by(Year, Code) %>% 
  slice(which.max(Weight))

#    Code Weight  Year          x
#   (int)  (int) (int)      (dbl)
# 1 27009    300  1975  1.3696332
# 2 30010    259  1975  1.1095553
# 3 27009    376  1977 -1.0672932
# 4 30010    501  1979  0.1152063
```

As a second solution you coud use the `data.table` package.

```
setDT(df)
df[order(-Weight) ,head(.SD,1), keyby = .(Year, Code)]
```

The results are the same.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot. The thing is that with your code I lose all my other columns between Code, Weight and Year.

Comment: @user181187 I added another variable. I think that matches the problem you are facing. With slice you can get the desired result.

Comment: thanks. very helpful. I am coding everyday in R since a month and there are so many functions that I don't know yet. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply run [aggregate](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/aggregate) in base R using `Code` and `Year` as the grouping. This will take max values of all other **numeric** columns:

```
finaldf <- aggregate(. ~ Code + Year, df, FUN = max)
```